# GoogleMaps V3 CheckResize() function

Tags: resize, google-maps-api-3, onclick

I have a google map that takes the users post code and loads in directions. The map then shrinks by around 300px in width. Although the map and options adjust to this new width, the route however remains as if the map did not shrink with not all of it in view.

I believe the way to checkResize() but I do not know how to use this. Essentially I would need to trigger it on an onClick event. How is this done. Maps API v3

Any ideas?

Marvellous

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
 google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

Comment: haha good one.  I was searching and noone answered so I thought I would :)